# Collapse dont remove .open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big problem. When I'm standing on a subpage on my website, I want my `.active` to have the class `open` in my mobile menu so it is open in my dropdown.

I have tried this:

```
jQuery('.active').addClass('open');
jQuery('.active i').attr("aria-expanded","true");
```

It add's these classes to the element I can see by inspecting, but as soon as i click and activate the mobile menu collapse, it removes those classes again. How can I prevent this from happening ? I can see this is `bootstrap.js` removing my classes on collapse.

Comment: You should be more explicit...

Comment: use Jquery to set classes on elements - dont change BootStrap

Comment: Lucky but thats what i already do, and it does add the classes. But when i collapse the mobilemenu it resets to "default" which is removing open classes and setting aria-expanded to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery(".dropdown.active").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

       jQuery('.mobilemenu .active').addClass('open');
        jQuery('.mobilemenu .active i').attr("aria-expanded","true");
    });

    jQuery(".mobilemenu .active i").click(function(){
        element = jQuery(".mobilemenu .active ul");
        if (element.hasClass ("openz")) {       
                element.removeClass('openz');
        } else {
                element.addClass('openz');
        }
    });
};
```

And my .openz class just has display:none; like this:

```
.openz {
    display: none !important;
}
```

BUT i cant get animations working.. all my other elements has a opacity:0 with transition on closing, but this just closes. I have tried to add fadeout, but all that happens is that it waits 0.5 seconds and then closes, no fadeout effect, what am i doing wrong? cant i use the fadeout effect?